# How to fire an event when BrowserWindow logs a console message?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'd like to get the event when the content of BrowserWindow logs a console message.

When we use a webView, 'console-message' event is fired when the guest window logs a console message like below.

```
webview. addEventListener ('console-message', function (e) {
  console.log('Guest page logged a message:', e.message);
});
```

However, I could not find any way to get this event with the content of BrowserWindow.
Is it possible to get console messages logged in 'https://github.com' in a below situation?

```
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false });
win.on('closed', function() {
  win = null;
});

win.loadUrl('https://github.com');
win.show();
```

Thank you for your support!!

Comment: I do not unserstand, what you want. You want to log the console.log messages from gihub.com? Which event are you expecting?

Comment: Here's some info about replacing console.log functionality with your own. (http://tobyho.com/2012/07/27/taking-over-console-log/) You could replace the functionality with one that console.log's AND sends the logged message to IPC main. (http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.0/api/ipc-main/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey For that you need to create the Prototype of the console object.

Here i have created prototype which will help you.

```js
function Console() {

  this.log = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e;
  }
}
var console = new Console();



console.log("Hello");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```